# Getting an error : Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I'm trying to write a C file from the [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/WorkingWStorage/WWStorage_StorageDevs/StorageDevFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000385-SW1) in my cocoa project however, I'm getting errors like

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_IOIteratorNext", referenced from:
   _MyGetDeviceFilePath in USBInterceptor.o
  "_IOMasterPort", referenced from:
   _MyFindEjectableCDMedia in USBInterceptor.o
  ....
```

Does somebody know what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error suggests that you need to add the IOKit framework to the link step of your project's build phases.

Comment: I already did, Still getting error